# Tables are not generated automatically after published to Azure and started the application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I took over an Asp.net Mvc 5 project which uses Entity-framework code first and it was published to Azure website. The `ApplicationDbContext (DefaultConnection)` was set correctly and the `Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)` is checked.

I deleted all the tables in the database and re-published the site. However, I got the error of *"Cannot find the object "dbo.xxxx" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."* when open the site in browser.

I tried to remove all the tables in the Azure Sql Server database and republished the project. However, only the following tables are created after opening the site.

```
AspNetRoles
AspNetUsers
AspNetUserClaims
AspNetUserLogins
AspNetUserRoles
__MigrationHistory
```

All the `DbSet<...>` of all the other tables are put in the `ApplicationDbContext` class in file `IdentityModels`.

Comment: what `IDatabaseInitializer` are you using? also you might wanna add `entity-framework` and `code-first-migrations` tags to your question

Comment: I think there is not any `IDatabaseInitializer` class. The project uses the standard template which doesn't have any `IDatabaseInitializer` class.

Answer (score 1):

try using the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer, check the section entitled "*Automatically Upgrading on Application Startup (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion Initializer)*"  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer)

it should look something like this

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext , Configuration>());
var appDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
appDbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```